# Get the value of the next table cell onclick javascript

Tags: javascript, html, click, cell

I am trying to get the value of the cell right of the cell where i click.

But right now I get the value of the cell I want, but I can click any cell in that row and get the desired value. But it should only be possible with the first column. So I click the any cell in the first column and I wanna get it's next neighbour cell value.

```
document.querySelector("#tableEventListId").addEventListener("click",event => {
        let dataTr = event.target.parentNode;
        let deleteEventId = dataTr.querySelectorAll("td")[1].innerText;
        console.log(deleteEventId);
        alert(deleteEventId);
```

Any help?

Comment: [nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling)

```js
document.getElementById('table1').onclick = function(event){
  //REM: Target
  var tElement = event.target;

  if(
    //REM: Only cells (=<td>)
    tElement.tagName === 'TD' &&
    
    //REM: Only first column cells
    tElement.parentNode.firstElementChild === tElement
  ){ 
    //REM: Next Elementsibling of Target or Null
    var tNext = tElement.nextElementSibling;
      
    if(tNext){
      console.log('TD: ', tElement.textContent);
      console.log('Next: ', tElement.nextElementSibling.textContent)
    }
  }
}
```

```css
table, td{
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<table id = 'table1'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A1</td>
      <td>B1</td>
      <td>C1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A2</td>
      <td>B2</td>
      <td>C2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A3</td>
      <td>B3</td>
      <td>C3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. This one helped me! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no HTML, so I can assume it's something like

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td class="first-column">1.1 (click here)</td>
    <td>1.2</td>
    <td>1.3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="first-column">2.1 (click here)</td>
    <td>2.2</td>
    <td>2.3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

According to this HTML, you can try

```js
const firstColumns = document.querySelectorAll(".first-column");

 for (let i = 0; i < firstColumns.length; i++) {
     firstColumns[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        let dataTr = event.target.parentNode;
        let deleteEventId = dataTr.querySelectorAll("td")[1].innerText;
        
        console.log(deleteEventId);
        alert(deleteEventId);
     });
 }
```

Have a look https://jsfiddle.net/vyspiansky/k2toLd8w/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to a an event on every `td` element of the table. Then use nextElementSibling to get a next cell.

Look code snippet to see the example.

```js
    const cells = document.querySelectorAll('#tableEventListId td');
    cells.forEach(cell => cell.onclick = function(){
        const nextCell = cell.nextElementSibling;
        if (nextCell)
            alert(nextCell.innerHTML);
    })
```

```html
<table id="tableEventListId">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>44</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>111</td>
      <td>222</td>
      <td>333</td>
      <td>444</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1111</td>
      <td>2222</td>
      <td>3333</td>
      <td>4444</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

If you want it to work only for cells at first column change the selector to `#tableEventListId td:first-child`.

Answer (score 0):

I have copied the code from above results. Thanks for the developer who shared this piece of code.  just to make reuse and help here if in case someone needs it. who is trying to access the table using class names.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('table1')[0].onclick = function(event) {
    /* mention the index value if your query by class name Target */
    var tElement = event.target;

    if (
        /* Only cells (=<td>) */
        tElement.tagName === 'TD' &&

        /* Only first column cells */
        tElement.parentNode.firstElementChild === tElement
    ) {
        /* Next Elementsibling of Target or Null */
        var tNext = tElement.nextElementSibling;

        if (tNext) {
            console.log('TD: ', tElement.textContent);
            console.log('Next: ', tElement.nextElementSibling.textContent)
        }
    }
}
```