# Why can't I get the task number from this HTML table when clicking on a button in the same row?

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to adjust this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63242115/11832197) to my situation, but I don't seem to be able to get the column containing the task numbers.

Here's the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/santosonit/zckhy7nq/15/#&togetherjs=L9JpmisNv2).

Also, I'm not sure if deleting the row from the table after getting the task deleted is correctly built.

This is the function beating me:

```
function deleteTask(){
  const delTask = document.querySelectorAll(".del-btn");
  let deleteTaskId = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < delTask.length; i++) {
      delTask[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
          let dataTr = event.target.parentNode;
          deleteTaskId = dataTr.querySelectorAll("td")[1].innerText;
      });
  }
  console.log(deleteTaskId)
  const td = event.target.parentNode;
  const tr =td.parentNode;
  tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
}
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Isn't the parent node of your button the `<td>` element that contains it, rather than the table row?

Comment: why are you adding a click handler to every `.del-btn` every time you click such a button?

Comment: Please post your HTML _here_, in a functional demo snippet. No need to send us to another site.

Comment: Hi, @MattEllen! I'm not really sure, actually. I've tried taking it off, but I can't get the task number when  I do it. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the solution for your problem [here](https://jsfiddle.net/puwc9nLo/1/). In your example, the value of event.target.parentNode would be the td within which the button is placed. To obtain the tr of the button, you need to get the parent of td and then get innerText to obtain the task id.

```
function deleteTask(){
  const delTask = document.querySelectorAll(".del-btn");
  let deleteTaskId = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < delTask.length; i++) {
      delTask[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
          let dataTr = event.target.parentNode;
          deleteTaskId = dataTr.parentNode.querySelectorAll("td")[1].innerText;
          console.log(deleteTaskId)
      });
  }
  console.log(deleteTaskId)
  const td = event.target.parentNode;
  const tr =td.parentNode;
  tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
}
```

Comment: Right on! Quick question from obviouskly a beginner: If the function is run upon the click, do I really need this ```delTask[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {})? Thank you!

Comment: I guess the outter ```console.log(deleteTaskId)``` doesn't log as intended. It seems that it keeps contained in the inner function, but how to spit it out so I can use it? Thank you!

Comment: That's right. The value of deleteTaskId is available only within the click function. Outside that it will be always 0.

Answer (score 2):

- I have used `forEach` loop to loop through the all `.del-btn`.
- I `onclick` event first i selected `TD` than I selected it's parent `tr`, after that I selected `td[1]` second column basically which contains task id , with reference of ``` tr``.(deletingRow.querySelectorAll("td")[1]) ``` and used `innerText` to get id value of that column.
- After that I am deleting `tr`.

```js
 if (deletingRow.parentNode) {
              deletingRow.parentNode.removeChild(deletingRow);
            }
```

```js
const table = document.querySelector("#dtable");

function deleteTask() {
  const delTask = document.querySelectorAll(".del-btn");
  let deleteTaskId = 0;
  delTask.forEach(deletedTask => {
    deletedTask.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      const deletingTd = e.target.parentNode;
      const deletingRow = deletingTd.parentNode;
      deleteTaskId = parseInt(deletingRow.querySelectorAll("td")[1].innerText);
      if (deletingRow.parentNode) {
        deletingRow.parentNode.removeChild(deletingRow);
        console.log(`Deleted task ID:${deleteTaskId}`);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-borderless table-hover table-vcenter" id="dtable">
  <thead style="white-space: nowrap">
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 4%" class="text-center">Client ID</th>
      <th style="width: 4%" class="text-center">Task No</th>
      <th style="width: 25%" class="text-center">Task</th>
      <th style="width: 4%" class="text-center">Date Assigned</th>
      <th style="width: 3%" class="text-center">Link To File</th>
      <th style="width: 17%" class="text-center">Notes</th>
      <th style="width: 12%" class="text-center">Approval</th>
      <th style="width: 24%" class="text-center">Comments</th>
      <th style="width: 24%" class="text-center">Delete Task</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center">AB002</td>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center">1</td>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center">review</td>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center">06/30/2022</td>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center"></td>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center"></td>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center"></td>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center"></td>
      <td class="del-btn"><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteTask()"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center">AB002</td>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center">2</td>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center">provide</td>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center">07/04/2022</td>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center"></td>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center"></td>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center"></td>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center"></td>
      <td class="del-btn"><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteTask()"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center">AB002</td>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center">3</td>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center">review</td>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center">07/07/2022</td>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center"></td>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center"></td>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center"></td>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center"></td>
      <td class="del-btn"><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteTask()"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center">AB002</td>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center">4</td>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center"></td>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center"></td>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center"></td>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center"></td>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center"></td>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center"></td>
      <td class="del-btn"><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteTask()"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center">AB002</td>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center">5</td>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center"></td>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center"></td>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center"></td>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center"></td>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center"></td>
      <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center"></td>
      <td class="del-btn"><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteTask()"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'll go with the previous one as it's much closer to what I had structured. Tested yours and it works! Thank you!